# Double linked list adding elements to Head

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to make a double linked list and there are 2 functions: First adds element to tail and second is supposed to add element right at the beggining but it does not work.

```
void AddNodeEnd (char addData)
    {
        nodePtr NewNode = new node;
        NewNode->next = NULL;
        NewNode->data = addData;


        if (head != NULL)
        {
            curr = head;
            while(curr->next != NULL)
            {
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            curr->next = NewNode;
        }
        else
        {
            head = NewNode;
        }
    }
    void AddNodeHead (char addData)
    {
        nodePtr NewNode = new node;
        NewNode->prev = NULL;
        NewNode->data = addData;

        head->prev = NewNode;
        NewNode->next = head;
        NewNode->prev = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: You don't update the `head` member variable to point to the new node.

Comment: Thought about using OOP (ie, a class etc)

Comment: Why not store both `head` and `tail`?

Comment: @BoBTFish Can you drop a little bit more hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `head` is a pointer to the first element of the list.

If you add a new node at the head of a list, the new node becomes the head.
So if you added your element at the head of the list you have to assign at the end: `head = newNode`.

```
void AddNodeHead (char addData)
{
    nodePtr NewNode = new node;
    NewNode->prev = NULL;
    NewNode->data = addData;

    if ( head != NULL )     // consider an empty list
      head->prev = NewNode;
    NewNode->next = head;   // this also works for an empty list
    head = newNode;         // <- this is missing in your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While appending nodes, you don't update the `head` to the new node.

As for the other function:

```
void AddNodeHead (char addData)
{
    ...
    NewNode->next = head;
    NewNode->prev = NULL; // you have this twice, not needed
}
```

What if `head` is `NULL`? You will try to access its `prev` member, resulting in a runtime error.